# Custom Production Meteor App /w Docker - Build Fails on Dependecies

Tags: node.js, meteor, docker

I am trying to rebuild simple/reliable Production Meteor Dockerfile.
It should

1.) Download Meteor

2.) Run Meteor Build on application

3.) Clean up source files

4.) Remove Meteor

5.) Install NodeJS

6.) Run `npm install` on production files

7.) Run app with forever.

I am building this bit by bit and seem to be getting errors when I try to run meteor build.

In debugging the Dockerfile looks like this...

```
FROM ubuntu:14.04

MAINTAINER Matt H

RUN mkdir /home/myApp
WORKDIR /home/myApp
ADD src /home/myApp

# Do basic updates
RUN apt-get update -q && apt-get clean

# Get curl in order to download curl
RUN apt-get install curl -y

# Install Meteor
RUN (curl https://install.meteor.com/ | sh)

RUN mkdir /home/app

# Build It
RUN cd /home/myApp/app \
        && meteor build \
        /home/app \
        --directory \
        --architecture os.linux.x86_64 \
        --server-only
```

I gives me different errors each time.

Example 1

```
=> Errors while initializing project:

While downloading natestrauser:font-awesome@4.6.3...:
error: socket hang up
```

Example 2

```
=> Errors while initializing project:

While downloading es5-shim@4.5.13...:
error: ETIMEDOUT

While downloading fourquet:jquery-toast@2.1.2_1...:
error: ETIMEDOUT

While downloading iron:controller@1.0.12...:
error: ETIMEDOUT

While downloading less@2.6.4...:
error: ETIMEDOUT

While downloading matb33:collection-hooks@0.8.1...:
error: ETIMEDOUT
```

If i build it locally on the Mac, works fine (takes ages) but works fine.

Looks as if cant get connection, but seems random - any thoughts?

Comment: Try mupx - https://github.com/arunoda/meteor-up/tree/mupx

Comment: @Vijay I use this for staging but want a better deployment using docker with Amazon ECS